# How do you remove an app from iPhone Configuration Utility?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, utility

I'm attempting to install an archive build of my app using iPhone Configuration Utility but am unable to.
The app appears in the Applications section, however when I click on the Devices section, then choose the Applications tab it isn't listed there.

I think this might be because I changed the app name and the app with the old name is still listed in iPhone Configuration Utility and as they have the same app id it may be getting confused.
However there seems to be no way to delete the old app from within iPhone Configuration Utility to see if this clears the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iPhone Configuration Utility, under Library->Applications, select the application and click Edit->Delete.